# Python - Different ways of printing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've installed PyDev into Eclipse, and when I do the print method in a .py file as `print "Hello World"` it didn't work. But then I did `print ("Hello World")` and it worked. I looked on the internet and everything says to do it without parentheses, but it doesn't work, and gives the error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Would this be because I have an old or new version of python?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to be using Python 3.

In Python 2 `print` was a keyword and the parentheses were not required.

In Python 3 `print` was changed to be a function. When calling a function the parentheses are required.

**Related**

- [What's New in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)